# Can having your front windshield replaced cause the check engine light to come on in a Honda fit?

Tags: honda, fit

Can having my front windshield replaced in a Honda fit cause the check engine light to come on?

Comment: No, not that I'm aware of

Answer (score 1):

This seems like it's coincidental unless the workers who replaced your windshield had to touch electronics to put it in. Go down to your local auto parts store, ask them to do a computer scan on your car, and come back to the internet and punch that code into a search engine to get an answer. If that code seems to be an electronic problem from a device around the windshield then go back to the company, explain what happened and what you've discovered since then and ask them to check it.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If your Honda has detection on the top of the screen, for automatic headlights,wipers etc this might have been damaged when the screen was changed, but as suggested get the code read.